# Take principal from client to server in WCF-Service

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-security

In my Application, I create on Client-side my own Principal-Object, which i set like

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = myPrincipal;
```

Now, when I call a WCF-Service (TCP/IP), I should also have this Principal in the Server-side Thread of this called WCF-Service. Is there something that I can configure to do this, or does I have to implement this myself?

Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Please see this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292183/what-value-should-the-serviceprincipalname-have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about windows principals, look at WCF authentication and security options. It's not trivial.

If you have a custom principal object, then my suggestion is to implement message inspectors, serialize the principal inside a message header and unpack it on the other side. This works pretty well for us in a number of projects, and doesn't require any special WCF settings.

Comment: Hi fejesjoco - I use custom principal. The idea with message inspector sound very interesting. Can you give me a sample how work with message insepctors?

Comment: This seems like a good example: http://adilmughal.com/blog/2011/10/client-additional-parameters-using-custom-headers-in-wcf/

Comment: The good thing about this approach is that you can send any kind of complex data contract object, and you can simply apply it to every call of a service, there's no need to add a new parameter to every service method one by one.

Answer (score 0):

this will be done implicitly as each request in WCF should have it's `Iprincipal.Identity` 
have you tried something like this in  your server side

```
IPrincipal principal =   Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
```